# Como fazer um OneToOne no JPA com chave primária composta?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Como colocar um User dentro de ServerUser?

Tentei assim. Ele cria o banco de dados, mas ele fica me jogando uma exceção

E também ele tá criando um novo campo user_idd, gostaria de usar o user_id da chave primária composta

`WARN 11548 --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "alter table server_user drop foreign key FKfcgk1es5us7bqb3o868xoawm7" via JDBC Statement`

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/blush
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=12345678
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

```
public class User implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    
    // ... outras propriedades
    // ... contrutores, getters e setters
}
```

```
public class ServerUser implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private ServerUserID id;
    
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_idd", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private User user;
    
    // ... outras propriedades
    // ... contrutores, getters e setters
}
```

Log: O Spring tá tentando dropar uma foreign key com o schema vazio

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.4.3)

2021-02-26 09:30:52.088  INFO 12300 --- [           main] c.s.discord.bot.DiscordBotApplication    : Starting DiscordBotApplication using Java 11.0.8 on GAPLS1894 with PID 12300 (D:\Projetos\Java\discord-bot\target\classes started by suchorskitbs in D:\Projetos\Java\discord-bot)
2021-02-26 09:30:52.091  INFO 12300 --- [           main] c.s.discord.bot.DiscordBotApplication    : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-02-26 09:30:52.766  INFO 12300 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-02-26 09:30:52.877  INFO 12300 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 98 ms. Found 2 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-02-26 09:30:53.383  INFO 12300 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-02-26 09:30:53.451  INFO 12300 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.28.Final
2021-02-26 09:30:53.619  INFO 12300 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-02-26 09:30:53.756  INFO 12300 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-02-26 09:30:53.997  INFO 12300 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-02-26 09:30:54.013  INFO 12300 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
Hibernate: alter table server_user drop foreign key FKfcgk1es5us7bqb3o868xoawm7
2021-02-26 09:30:54.700  WARN 12300 --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "alter table server_user drop foreign key FKfcgk1es5us7bqb3o868xoawm7" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table server_user drop foreign key FKfcgk1es5us7bqb3o868xoawm7" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlString(SchemaDropperImpl.java:375) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaDropperImpl.java:359) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applyConstraintDropping(SchemaDropperImpl.java:331) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropFromMetadata(SchemaDropperImpl.java:230) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.performDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:154) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:112) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:145) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:318) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:468) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1259) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1153) ~[spring-context-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:907) ~[spring-context-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:582) ~[spring-context-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1311) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1300) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at com.suchorski.discord.bot.DiscordBotApplication.main(DiscordBotApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'discordbot.server_user' doesn't exist
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:762) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:646) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar:5.4.28.Final]
    ... 35 common frames omitted

Hibernate: drop table if exists server_user
Hibernate: drop table if exists user
Hibernate: create table server_user (server_id bigint not null, user_id bigint not null, last_message datetime not null, level bigint not null, messages bigint not null, xp bigint not null, user_idd bigint not null, primary key (server_id, user_id)) engine=InnoDB
Hibernate: create table user (id bigint not null, coins bigint not null, last_get_coins datetime not null, primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB
Hibernate: alter table server_user add constraint UK_hugwiojr3js5onvae4qodmwe8 unique (user_idd)
Hibernate: alter table server_user add constraint FKfcgk1es5us7bqb3o868xoawm7 foreign key (user_idd) references user (id)
2021-02-26 09:30:55.635  INFO 12300 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-02-26 09:30:55.645  INFO 12300 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-02-26 09:30:56.297  INFO 12300 --- [           main] c.s.discord.bot.DiscordBotApplication    : Started DiscordBotApplication in 4.618 seconds (JVM running for 6.081)
2021-02-26 09:30:57.219  INFO 12300 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDA                  : Login Successful!
2021-02-26 09:30:57.497  INFO 12300 --- [inWS-ReadThread] n.d.j.internal.requests.WebSocketClient  : Connected to WebSocket
2021-02-26 09:30:57.782  INFO 12300 --- [inWS-ReadThread] net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDA                  : Finished Loading!
```

Comment: Qual o log do banco de dados? Como ele lançou o erro na execução do DDL, provavelmente isso foi registrado nos logs do SGBD.

Comment: Não aparece nada no log erro. @MarcosAlexandre

Answer (score -1):

Resolvido

`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop`

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@MapsId("userId")
private User user;
```